# Apache POI: using table column names in formula's

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've got a table in an existing worksheet, and I want to add more rows, copying the existing formulas. 
The problem seems to be that the apache POI formula parser doesn't quite get the syntax used in excel: the formula I have looks like this:

```
=[@[column1_name]]/[@[column2_name]]
```

which is read to something like this:

```
Summary[[#This Row],[column1_name]]/Summary[[#This Row],[column2_name]]
```

(The name of the Table is "Summary"). However, trying to evaluate the formula fails with

```
|FormulaParseException Specified named range 'Summary' does not exist in the current workbook.  org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseNonRange (FormulaParser.java:547)
```

Anyone had the same issue? Proposed solutions?

Comment: by the way, for now I'm doing something very ugly like this: =INDIRECT("H"&ROW())/INDIRECT("E"&ROW()), but that's really not a nice way to ask users to add formulas...

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. It would still be nice to find a proper way to solve this, but for now, the indirect function works for me

Answer (score 0):

A good workaround is to de-reference the tables themselves in excel. You can do so by selecting the table, right clicking and selecting Table -> Convert to Range. This will change all the formulas to regular cell references. I know it's not a programmatic way to solve, but it will allow you to evaluate the formulas.